# SwiftUI passing argument to init and assigning it to @State variable

Tags: state, swiftui

I have SwiftUI view that has some @State properties like isSelected 
I would like to init state of this variable via constructor.

Here is sample code

```
 @State var isSelected : Bool = false

    init(user: User, isSelected: Bool, onChange: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = { _ in }) {
        self.user = user
        self.onChange = onChange

        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }
```

But unfortunately this does not work and View inits with isSelected set to false.

Why is it this way? How could I solve this issue?

Comment: @State needs to be set as `private`

Comment: yes this _isSelected = State(initialValue: isSelected) is what I was looking for